# NS-3 TCP vs. UDP throughput

Tags: performance, sockets, networking, tcp, ns-3

I'm a new NS-3 user. I'm trying to find and verify the throughput of TCP wireless network. When experimenting with the "ht-wifi-network.cc"(http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen-release/ht-wifi-network_8cc_source.html) in the example file, I used the default settings,which is a UDP flow, and then tried TCP flow. Then I noticed 2 things:

1. Throughput is very low comparing with datarate, UDP is 22.78 / 65 and TCP is 11.73 / 65. Is  this how the result should be like? Because I was expecting at least 30 Mbps out of 65 Mbps.
2. UDP throughput is almost twice of the TCP throughput. But I expected that TCP throughput would be higher.

Can somebody help and explain why? Thanks!

Comment: Wireless networks are characterised by widely-varying latency.  This can cause delays with reliable protocols, like TCP, running on top.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @MartinJames. But is it normal to have about 12 Mbps throughput when datarate is 65 Mbps?